# How to calculate the discharged current of a capacitor from the discharge curve?

Tags: capacitor, current, current-measurement, discharge, time-constant

I observed the discharge of a capacitor on an energy harvester chip via an oscilloscope. The Output was used to power a BLE module.

[image]

I know the capacitor value, discharge time, and the top and bottom voltage. I don't think I know my load resistor because it is a bit complicated to measure.

Is there a way to measure the total discharged current?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by total current? I'm guessing you mean total charge, which is the integral of the current over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the capacitance C (assuming it is constant) then the slope of the curve is proportional to the discharge current.

i(t) = C \$dv\over dt\$

Comment: Will that give me the total current consumed via the discharge?

Comment: Current is a function of time, in general. The slope and C gives you the net current out of the capacitor at any given time If you want the total energy (joules) you need to integrate the power (watts) over some interval. If you want the total charge (coulombs) you need to integrate the current (amperes) over the period in question.

Comment: I made the calculation and it is up to 280 uA. However, I remember when I power my chip directly with no capacitor. the current consumption fluctuates between two values due to the duty cycle of the transmitted information. So, does it make sense that my slope is linear and I have one value current representation for current consumption?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to measure the total discharged current?

Yes, but you need to be able to simplify the circuit to an RC circuit (which means essentially one capacitor and one resistor). You can measure the fall time, which should be exponential. The graph in your post looks more linear (and not exponential) which means that there are probably more complex circuit elements causing the decay of the circuit as it powers off.

If it is exponential, if you could get the data into excel or something like that and do an exponenital fit, then you could find the decay constant and relate it to RC (decay constant = RC).